# Symfony5 service: autowire arguments not working

Tags: symfony, symfony5

Controller:

```
use App\Service\ExtraService;
...
$extra = new ExtraService();
```

Service:

```
namespace App\Service;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class ExtraService
{
private $em;    
private $session;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em,SessionInterface $session){
    $this->em      = $em;
    $this->session = $session;
...
```

After reading the documentation, I would have expected to load (inject, autowire) the Doctrine EntityManager and Session entities into the $em and $session properties to be ready for use inside the ExtraService class. Instead, I get:

> Too few arguments to function App\Service\ExtraService::__construct(), 0 passed

I checked services.yaml and I have:

```
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

I even tried to explicitly configure arguments in services.yaml like in the manual (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#services-explicitly-configure-wire-services), but I cannot get the right code to make this work.

Comment: What do the docs say about the relationship between the PHP new operator and the Symfony DI container?

Comment: you controller should not have a `... = new Service` but instead the controller constructor or route should have a *parameter* `ExtraService $extraService`, and symfony should provide it. `new` circumvents dependency injection.

Comment: Oh, okay, I missed that. Thanks, I'm still learning Symfony's ways.

Comment: @Jakumi this is the answer i need, wasted 2 days googling it, thank you so much. fuc#@ Cool answer

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring in Symfony is usually done automatically when `autowire: true` and `configure: true` which is the case for your config. However, there are usually two **simple** ways to achieve this. (and some more complicated ones*).

Using `new ExtraService` will never autowire arguments. The container has to generate the Service, this will be done for examples if you add ExtraService to a constructor/route method of a controller or the constructor of a (symfony) command.

I.e., the simplest are:

1. adding it to the controller's constructor (when you need the service in multiple or all routes)

```php
class YourController extends AbstractController
{
    private $extraService;

    public function __construct(
        ExtraService $extraService
    ) {
        $this->extraService = $extraService;
    }
}
```

then you can use it via `$this->extraService->...` in your methods.

2. add the service to your method signature:

```php
class YourController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route('/some-route')
     */
    public function someRoute(ExtraService $extraService)
    {
         // autowiring at its best ;o)
    }
}
```

(using old php <= 7.4 code and annotations, in php >= 8 you can use Symfony 5.2's [`#Route`](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-php-8-attributes) [attributes](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8#attributes-rfc) and in [constructor property promotion](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8#constructor-property-promotion-rfc) instead)

* one of the more complicated ones: defining a tag, and having a dedicated setter for all classes with that tag. another: explicitly defining how to initialize/instantiate the controller (or whatever class) via the services.yaml and complicated stuff. The symfony docs should be of some help here, but it's usually not required and thus omitted here. ;o)